# format for setting a boolean request header in django

Tags: python, django, http-headers

I have created a response object in my django view by calling HttpResponse

```
myResponse = HttpResponse("Here is some text")
```

and I want to set set the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header on the response to be true. Should this be set with a python string like I do for other headers

```
myResponse['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true'
```

or with a python boolean

```
myResponse['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = True
```

or will either work? (and if they will both technically work, is one more "correct")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go with:

```
myResponse['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true'
```

If the Boolean `True` is serialized as "True" then some browsers might not accept it

Comment: Once I fixed the other problems, I was able to test the options and True does get serialized to "True" and causes the request to fail.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the string version is correct:

https://github.com/prasanthn/django-dcors/blob/master/dcors/dcorsmiddleware.py#L67